# phpMyAdmin don't have permission to read file

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a secure connection between PHP and MySQL database.

In order to do this, I need to store the DB infos in a separated file, with `-r--------` permission (readonly for owner). But doing like this, PHP seems impossible to open the file, making impossible the connection.

What do I have to do? Do I have to run phpMyAdmin as root?

EDIT:

This is the result of the `ls -l` command. Thank you for help.

```
-r-----r-- 1 root root 56 Jul 10 13:01 db.ini
```

Comment: Can you also add info which HTTP you are using (apache, nginx) and which user is used to start http server.

Comment: Im using Apache. Logged in with my personal user wich i created during Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You web server must be able to read file which contains DB credentials. Since it's not a good practice to start services as root user, you should change ownership of **db.ini** file:

```
chown <user>:root db.ini
chmod 0400 db.ini
```

Instead of  use username of user which is used to start Apache. Different Linux distributions use different users to start Apache (**apache**, **http**, **www-data**).

You can find this out by displaying status of Apache service:

```
systemctl status apache2
```

or for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora:

```
systemctl status httpd
```

**Main PID** filed shows PID and username you need.